# changing the order of graphs using facet_nested_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggh4x

I have a set of data that I wanted to split by two variables, the first being "genome" the second being "Clade". I want each row to have graphs of the same "genome" (which include Dniva, Echei, Iindi and Mpgym) and each row to be "Clade". the issue is that each genome doesnt have the same number of Clades in it. so some rows might have 2 columns others maybe 5. is there a way to organise them in this way?

#this is my code so far

```
ggplot(LTR_Gypsy_CodingDomains_3, aes(y = CodingDomains, x = Number)) + 
  geom_col(fill = "#669933", color = "black") +
  facet_nested_wrap(vars(genome, Clade), bleed = TRUE, scales = "free_y") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 5), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 5), strip.text =     element_text(size = 6, margin = margin()))
```

#it produced the graphs below

[image]

as you can see some of the genomes are spread across two rows. how can i make it so that each genome is on its own row.

I am very new to this so please let me know if I've made any mistakes!

Comment: When you refer to "rows" and "columns", are you refering to rows and columns of your *data frame* or of the *faceted plot* in your graphic?  Your text suggests the former, your code and graphic the latter.  The solutions for each case are very different.

Comment: I'd suggest making separate facted plots for each genome and then sticking them together with patchwork or cowplot.

Comment: @Limey thank you for answering! I meant the latter, changing the rows and columns of the faceted plot in the graphic. sorry for not being clear